# How to open Scroll & Zoom and change Natura Scrolling ? [AppleScript]

Tags: ios, applescript

Im trying to write a simple apple script that can change the Natura Scrolling.

I wrota a Code that can open Trackpad from System Settings, but hale no idea how to pick Scroll & Zoom and ten change natural scrolling...

Can you help me with this? Also, maybe I can do in in Terminal? I tried:
`$ defaults write -g com.apple.swipescrolldirection -bool false` 
but it's not working...

Here is what I already wrote:

```
tell application "System Settings"
    activate
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Settings"
        click menu item "Trackpad" of menu "View" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

And it's working fine (Trackpad in System Settings shows up)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "System Settings"
    activate
    delay 1
    set current pane to pane id "com.apple.Trackpad-Settings.extension"
    delay 1
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Settings"
        tell window "Trackpad"
            tell group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1
                click (radio buttons of tab group 1 where description is "Scroll & Zoom")
                delay 1
                click checkbox "Natural scrolling" of group 1 of scroll area 1
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Note that this will break next time Apple changes the System Settings UI in these places.

Also the `delay 1` is very generous, you'll probably be okay with `delay 0.5` depending on how fast your system is. Of course `delay` is the lazy way out and the better way would be to `repeat until ...` and wait for the UI to actually change instead of waiting for an arbitrary period of time.

You can play with Apple Script by inserting `return UI elements of THING` or `return properties of THING` and look in the Result box of Script Editor.